# How to factorize the quintic polynomial $2x^5 + 6x^4 + 7x^3 + 21x^2 + 5x + 15$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quintics

The polynomial is

$$2x^5 + 6x^4 + 7x^3 + 21x^2 + 5x + 15$$

I want to find out the easiest way I can do factorize. Please show me the steps.

Comment: What are some methods of factoring that you have learned? Perhaps edit the post to include some of your effort.

Comment: Divide the quintic polynomial by $x+3$, make $y := x^2$ and then solve the quadratic in $y$.

Answer (score 4):

By the rational root test we see that $x=-3$ is a root. Using polynomial division, we see that the polynomial factors as 
$$
(x+3)(x^2+1)(2x^2+5).
$$
Alternatively we see that $i$ is a root, hence $x^2+1$ is a factor.